# java android i/o Failure Exception when creating a ParseObject

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I started a Parse server instance on AWS where I want to store my data from an android application.

In the module's gradle I inserted the below under dependencies

```
implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3'
```

and created a new application which initializes parse configuration

```
import android.app.Application;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

public class StarterApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId(myAppId)
                .clientKey(myClientKey)
                .server(serverAddress)
                .build()
        );

        ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ExampleObject");
//        object.put("id", "123");
//        object.put("name", "jack");



        object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException ex) {
                if (ex == null) {
                    Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
                } else {
                    Log.i("Parse Result", "Failed" + ex.toString());
                }
            }
        });


        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    }
}
```

This is all new to me and I am following a 3-year-old course on Android development. when I run this, the exception keeps getting caught with the same error:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
```

My android Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.parsetest2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".StarterApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where is the error coming from? how can it be solved?

Comment: Hey @user7331538.
I'm facing the same problem. Do you found a solution for this? I tried what Fouad Raafat provided in his answer, but that did not work either. I'm getting really frustrated about this problem...

Answer (score 2):

The Main problem is that you are not connecting to the server.

[1]-make sure you have added your application id and client id in `AndroidManifest`

**change _App_Id_here and _Client_key_here with your keys something like "ISIGDGU4YGCE673".

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.SERVER_URL"
            android:value="https://parseapi.back4app.com" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="_App_Id_Here_" /> //<- put your key
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="_client_Key_here_" /> //<- put your key
```

[2]- add repositories `{ maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } }`to your `build.gradle(Project:xyz)`

[3]- make sure u change the.server field to your parse server, AppId and clientKey:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
  .applicationId(myAppId)//"myAppId" should be sth like ->"ASHWD63787EDXSG8"
  .clientKey(myClientKey)//should be sth like ->"tdf29yedih287823"
  .server(serverAddress)//something like-> "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
  .build()
        );
```

get those keys from your server's dashboard settings -> keys

Answer (score 2):

This problem can also occur in case your hosted parse server is on HTTP server rather than on HTTPS. Because Android 9.0 and above will not let you use clear text information over the HTTP. So if it is the case then you can do the following:

- In you manifest file, and in your manifest tag add the `android:targetSandboxVersion="1"` line. So it will look like

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
   android:targetSandboxVersion="1">
```

- In your manifest file, in application tag add the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` line. So it will look like

```xml
<application
        android:name=".Example"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. For some reason the Parse server dashboard which comes from the AWS service. That is for example,http://ec2-18-220-53-0.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com doesnt have an apps category, You'd notice it only shows my Bitnami Parse API without an apps option.  This means firstly, you're not able to pass data to any app on the server which should be available. Secondly, connecting the server to your android app would not work as the Master key is actually now different from the Client key in recent times.

Instead of AWS use Back4App which would work the same exact way. Back4App is a scalable back-end service based on the Parse Server Platform.

Pros:

You dont need to use an SSH client to connect to server and retrieve your APP ID, Client Key or server url. Everything is under server setting on the dashboard.

Proceed to Back4App:

Step 1: Create an Account on back4app

Step 2: Create an App, you can name it instagramandroid based on this tutorial

Step 3: follow all the remaining info in the link here and every thing should work fine . https://www.back4app.com/docs/pages/android/how-to-build-an-android-app-on-back4app

Note: When adding the parse dependency, the latest one is 1.17.3. which would work very fine unless you may want to use 1.20.0, i tried it and doesn't really work. Add it like you'll normally add a dependency in your gradle file : 'implementation com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3'

Comment: To use the last one, you must change from  'implementation com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3' to "implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:1.20.0".
NOTE: there are some changes that you might need (if you're using push notifications, for example), I recommend you to test it and check the releases here: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/releases

Comment: Yes @RamosCharles, additionally to your answer, I would like to recommend the documentation that is showing how to migrate the project to AndroidX, please check: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate